# In Magento2 How do i solve this JsonSerializable error

Tags: magento2, php, json, magento2.4.6

When we open frontend at that time below error is generated.

`During inheritance of JsonSerializable: Uncaught Exception: Deprecated Functionality: Return type of GeoIp2\Model\AbstractModel::jsonSerialize() should either be compatible with JsonSerializable::jsonSerialize(): mixed`

We have use given below screenshot solution but it is not working.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNf9b.png

We are using Magento version:- 2.4.6,PHP version:- 8.2.

anyone idea of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since `JsonSerializable::jsonSerialize()` declared `mixed` as the return type, you need to declare `mixed` as the return type for your method `GeoIp2\Model\AbstractModel::jsonSerialize`:

```
public function jsonSerialize(): mixed
```

Comment: Thank you ,but it is given another error some in given below screenshot.
- https://i.imgur.com/8kO8bPt.png

Comment: Check apache2 server logs and magento2 logs